# highlight text in Grocery Crud

Tags: codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I'd like to highlight text in a specific field Estado(state) currently it has 3 states, "activo", "inactivo" and "pendiente"   , when it matchs to pendiente i want to highlight the text changing the color to red, but no idea where to do the corresponding modifications.

I'm attaching an image to a better view.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it called [callback_column](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_column) it will "process" the column before it shown to user.

here's example

```
public function webpages()
{
$c = new grocery_CRUD();   
$c->set_table('status');
$c->columns('estado','email_propietario');
$c->callback_column('estado',array($this,'_callback_active_state'));
$output = $c->render();
$this->_view_output($output);
}

public function _callback_active_state($value, $row)
{
  if ($row->estado == 'pendiente'){
  return "<pre style='color:red'>".$row->estado."</pre>";}
  else {return $row->estado;}
}
```